# Using Selenium to navigate URLs on a website without having to reload all the Javascript all the time/refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium to scrape particular URLs of a website. The site requires users to be logged in. Each time when calling `.get(url)` it takes about 2-3 seconds to load all the Javascript and my profile. I have noticed however that when I navigate to the URL normally via the ui buttons my user profile is not reloaded each time and it is much quicker. Fully loading of the user profile is required before the information becomes available that I am scraping.

Is it possible in Selenium to navigate to my desired URLs easily, without having page refreshes that cause JS to reload each time? Preferably without having to button click to reach the URL?

Comment: depends on the site, but you can try just setting the location...  execute_script("location.assign(newurl)"); (It'll depend on if the site uses hashchange and how it's designed to save bookmarks and retain back button functionality...) Seems easier to just click.

Comment: @pcalkins Tried, but still reloads the js on the page. Clicking works fine for now and is slightly faster

Comment: It's a PWA, right? It's probably fetching the data for the other pages so you can try that.